# First expression in pattern design

Tags: java, regex

I want to divide a long String for smaller blocks.
i used a regex: h1[\W|\D|]*(h1|\Z) but i got only first block.

my online regex tester:
https://regex101.com/r/sP1bP2/2

input:

> h1. headLineOneh1. *PureNG*# \"*Part*\":https://pure1.pdf**
>   \"Part1\":https://pure2.pdf** \"Part2\":https://pure3.pdf**
>   \"Part3\":https://pure4.pdf# \"*Fakt*\":https://pure5.pdf**
>   \"Fakt1\":https://pure5.pdf** \"Fakt2\":https://pure6.pdf# \"*WZ*
>   *(wydanie)*\":https://pure7.pdf# \"*ZA*\":https://pure8.pdf** \"PA\":https://pure9.pdf# \"*Close*\":https://pure11.pdf**
>   \"Close1\":https://pure12.pdf# \"*Stany*\":https://pure13.pdfh1.
>   Astent# \"*Call Back*\":https://stent1.pdf# \"*Bon
>   Backs*\":https://stent2.pdfh1. Obile# \"*Mobi
>   Kampa*\":https://Obile.pptx

the expected output:

> 1: h1. headLineOne
>   2: h1. *PureNG*# \"*Part*\":https://pure1.pdf**
>   \"Part1\":https://pure2.pdf** \"Part2\":https://pure3.pdf**
>   \"Part3\":https://pure4.pdf# \"*Fakt*\":https://pure5.pdf**
>   \"Fakt1\":https://pure5.pdf** \"Fakt2\":https://pure6.pdf# \"*WZ*
>   *(wydanie)*\":https://pure7.pdf# \"*ZA*\":https://pure8.pdf** \"PA\":https://pure9.pdf# \"*Close*\":https://pure11.pdf**
>   \"Close1\":https://pure12.pdf# \"*Stany*\":https://pure13.pdf
>   3: h1.
>   Astent# \"*Call Back*\":https://stent1.pdf# \"*Bon
>   Backs*\":https://stent2.pdfh1. Obile# \"*Mobi
>   Kampa*\":https://Obile.pptx

Comment: Can you show some of your code that uses this expression?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
(h1\. .*?)(?=h1\.)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sP1bP2/3)

Comment: @Derek: If you have large strings, I would not recommend this lazy dot matching approach. Use an unroll-the-loop regex I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can just split the string right at the location before `h1.`:

```
String re = "(?=h1\\.\\s+)"; 
String str = "h1. headLineOneh1. *PureNG*# \"*Part*\":https://pure1.pdf** \"Part1\":https://pure2.pdf** \"Part2\":https://pure3.pdf** \"Part3\":https://pure4.pdf# \"*Fakt*\":https://pure5.pdf** \"Fakt1\":https://pure5.pdf** \"Fakt2\":https://pure6.pdf# \"*WZ* _(wydanie)_\":https://pure7.pdf# \"*ZA*\":https://pure8.pdf** \"PA\":https://pure9.pdf# \"*Close*\":https://pure11.pdf** \"Close1\":https://pure12.pdf# \"*Stany*\":https://pure13.pdfh1. Astent# \"*Call Back*\":https://stent1.pdf# \"*Bon Backs*\":https://stent2.pdfh1. Obile# \"*Mobi Kampa*\":https://Obile.pptx"; 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split(re)));
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Em699r)

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oP5uI0/1)

If you need a matching regex, you can use this unrolled regex:

```
h1\.\s+[^h]*(?:h(?!1\.\s+)[^h]*)*
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oP5uI0/2)

This regex is basically the same as `h1\.\s+.*?(?=h1\.\s+)` (matching `h1.` and all that is not `h1.` after it), but is more effecient.

And here is [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/fsU32d):

```
String str = "YOUR_STRING"; 
String pattern1 = "h1\\.\\s+[^h]*(?:h(?!1\\.\\s+)[^h]*)*";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```